# Contents are missing but shown when switching to another theme in wordpress

Tags: plugins, content

I was surprised this morning to hear that the contents on my WP site are erased, said my client. I tried disable all plugins one by one, but the problem still exists. I also changed the memory limit via the wp-config and that could not solve the problem either. Then I switched to another theme, twenty-eleven and twenty-twelve, they all show those missing contents.

This is my first time building a WP site, and I've no idea why it occurs. http://www.dcaredental.com/news-event/tv-interviews/

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If, switching theme shows the contents, then the problem is with the theme, not with the plugins. Confirm it by disabling and/or enabling all of your plugins while using the theme you are currently using. If the result is same dis-satisfactory, then the problem is with the theme, no doubt. If so, then you have to look at the `category.php` and/or `single.php` and/or `header.php` and/or `index.php`/`front-page.php` pages for any leak into the codes.

Comment: this theme previously shows the contents, but this morning they have gone, I don't know if my client have inserted contents that could lead to this.

Comment: If the hidden thing is related to a single content, then open the page/post editor, then copy them to a notepad, and then hit the HTML tab on the editor, and clear the text field completely. Then copy the text from the notepad, and paste them into the editor, and see the preview and then publish. (It will resolve the problem if it is caused by only a single or multiple contents solely).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I found the bug in my page.php where I have made some changes that lead to not showing the contents

Comment: nice, listing a bug is fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with plugins.

Everything on your site is using localhost. This will *only work on your own machine* - it will not work on a server, over the web.

You need to (at least) change the paths on your site.

Comment: I just made some change while you saw it, the bug is now fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can go into phpMyAdmin through whatever web host your client is using and check on the database directly. Click into your database and then check the `wp_posts` table to see if there is actually an content for the theme to show.

From what you said it sounds like the database is probably empty. If it is then you can export anything that's on your local server. If it's not empty then you might try a fresh install of wordpress to rule out anything related to your particular copy.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's my own mistake. It's now fixed